# Django Field is showing up in one view but not the other

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I'm just starting out with Django and I have a problem where, **when I added a field to my model (JobPost which inherits from models.Model) and it migrated successfully I can see and interact with the new field when I create a job post, but not when I view the JobPost (which is displayed using crispy forms using the {{ form|crispy }} tag.**

I have added the field name to my fields = [''] in my views.py

**models.py**

```py
class JobPost(models.Model):
#constants
CLEARANCE_LEVELS=[(...),]

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
clearance_required = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLEARANCE_LEVELS, default='None')
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py**

```py
class JobDetailView(DetailView):
    model = JobPost

class JobCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = JobPost
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'clearance_required']
    # form_valid checks if the user is logged in
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**jobpost_form.html**

```html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} <!--Used to prevent some XSS Attacks (Cross-site request forgery) -->
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Job Post</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**jobpost_detail.html**

```html
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="mb-2 article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-1" href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ object.author }}</a> <!-- BROKEN LINK: SIMPLY TAKES TO CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER-->
            <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            {% if object.author != user %}
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" href="{% url 'user-jobs' object.author.username %}">See all jobs the user applied to</a>
            {% endif %}
            <div>
                {% if object.author == user %}
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1 float-right" href="{% url 'user-jobs' object.author.username %}">See all jobs the user applied to</a>
                <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'job-update' object.id %}">Update Job Posting</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'job-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-1">
            <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

So when I view it in my browser, I see the "clearance_required" field when I create a job post. But when I just view the job post, it only shows the title and description, not the new clearance_required field. I don't know how I can get it to display.

Here's a picture of the issue: 
Notice how the clearance field is missing in the second picture
[image: The Create Job Page]
[image]

Comment: This is unclear. Forms are for creating and editing, you don't display a post using forms. Where is the view and template that do that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well I'm not actually using a "form" to display a post. In my model, you can see that I'm using the models.Model as my base for the post.

EDIT: I see what you mean now. My template for the actual display of the post itself has now been added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually output in `object.clearance_required` in `jobpost_detail.html`, because I cannot see it?

And by the way, if you output it, you should use `object.get_clearance_required_display`, [because it is a field with choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).